# How do I update an NPM install script?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npx

We are creating a tool for our Thesis, and we would like to update the npm install command on NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-bratus/cli). I think it is not possible to do it through the NPM website, but maybe it is possible through running a command?

We would basically like to change the command that you can see in the photo to npm i -g @react-bratus/cli.

I have tried many different things, but didn't manage to achieve it. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You can't, I guess. But I like the question.

Comment: @GOTO0 Yeah, it's weird that you can't do it. I have tried a lot but no updates